# Laravel Request ip address for login users

Tags: mysql, laravel

i made **login_history** table with fields **user_id**  foreign for **users** table , **ip_address** and **created_at** i need to very time to login user save it in **login_history** table now i'm using 
Listeners or **last_login** **users** using laravel 5.2 with this code

```
 public function handle(Login $event)
         {
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $data = new LoginHistory();
    $event->user->$data->user_id = $user->id;
    $event->user->$data->created_at = Carbon::now();
    $event->user->$data->ip_address = Request::getClientIp();
    $event->user->$data->save();
     }
```

**but this not i want 
please any one can help for changing this code i have model created

```
class LoginHistory extends Model

    {
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }
    }
```

and i get this error

> Cannot use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as User because the name is
>   already in use

thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow isn’t a website to architect your app for you. However, a listener is _exactly_ where this code should be. It doesn’t belong in a controller or “something else”.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have a Model for the `LoginHistory` pivot table. In any controller method, you can use the following code.

```
$user = auth()->user();
LoginHistory::create(['user_id'=>$user->id,'ip_address' => Request::getClientIp(), 'created_at'=>Carbon::now()]);
```

And if you don't have the model, you can use the DB facade to do the same.

Comment: yes i have model public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

Comment: @fido You need to re-study the framework.. Read [this tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart) and [this one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate) afterwards.. I believe you'll have all the answers you need. Don't just read them, practice them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) in laravel in handle method you can insert the data

Answer (score 0):

```
$event->user->$data->ip_address = \Request::ip(),
```

Comment: Try to add some comments for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how.why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.